# installing PostgreSQL on Cygwin as a service

Tags: database, postgresql, cygwin, database-connection, daemon

I'm a novice trying to install Postgresql on Cygwin as a service. I have been following the steps listed in this URL: http://www.smartpixie.com/wiki/Tech/CygwinPostgreSQL.twiki.html

Everything was working fine until I got to the step where I had to create a user and a database for myself, in my /usr/sbin directory the "createuser" file exists but the "createdb" file does not. So, as suggested by the steps, I attempted to connect to the database as the SYSTEM user and then create the database/user roles later. However, I come across this error whenever I try to connect to the database.

```
$ psql -U SYSTEM postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have to run PostgreSQL under Cygwin? PostgreSQL has a [Windows installer](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/). It's trivial for application code running under Cygwin to connect to a PostgreSQL database running under Windows.

Comment: I am aware that PostgreSQL has a Windows installer but one of the requirements for this project i'm trying to do is to install it as a service on Cygwin.

Comment: That page at smartpixie.com was written five years ago.  Did you try just installing through the Cygwin package manager?

Comment: Can i use the package manager to install postgreSQL as a service? If so, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had trouble with setting up services under Cygwin a few years ago--seems like I had to first install an IPC daemon, or something like that. I *hope* they've worked out the kinks by now.

Comment: What need is filled by the requirement that it be run as a service under cygwin?  Try as I might, I am having trouble thinking of a reason this might be. Are they trying to port over UNIX-specific C-language stored procedures?

Comment: the downsides include much reduced performance, headaches like this, and much, much more.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend against running PostgreSQL over Cygwin.  There isn't a real use case I can see since there is now a native port and Cygwin ends up adding quite a bit of overhead to things like IPC calls.  You won't get good performance out of it, and I can't actually think of any case where cygwin would be a better fit than mingw for c-language stored procedures.  So please question whether this is really a requirement and explore other options first.

Now if you still need to do so, the process isn't easy, but is documented at http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3DC76EA4.7090503@usa.net

Basically you have to install the ipc service first, then use cygrunsrv to create a Windows service for PostgreSQL dependent on it.  Then you can run `net start ipc-daemon` and then `net start postgresql`